# Django - Server only works in one browser until I restart it

Tags: django, server

I have a Django project (it's a big project meanwhile) and I can only connect to it via localhost using one browser (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, it doesn't matter which browser I use). When I connect to it once, Django is "locked" in this browser. When I try to connect to Django using another browser, it gets timed out. When I restart it I can again choice which browser I would like to use. But then Django gets "locked" again in this browser.

Example:

Django Server starts; I use Chrome; I can't use Opera, Firefox or any other browser anymore.

Django Server restarts; I use Opera; I can't use Chrome, Firefox or any other browser anymore.

I know this isn't a question about code but I don't know where this question fits  except for Stackoverflow.
Do you have any idea?

**EDIT**
I also have this strange behaviour when I use incognito.

**EDIT 2**
I tried to reset the middlewares but that didn't change anything.

Comment: It's hard to advise without seeing a code, but I can assume that maybe there some long task called when you open it in the first browser and that's why it doesn't respond to another: try to open django page in 2 tabs of one browser and see what happens. Also please share the view that is working for the page you are trying to connect.

Comment: I can open as many tabs as I want on one browser. It doesn't matter which view I call.

Comment: @SergeyPugach No idea?